# I can't manage to change the color of the text in my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a simple webpage for a class that presents images in a slider format. I have created a navigation bar on top of the page that links to different pages. Normally, the text in the navigation bar is white, but for some reason it remains the color purple. I just can't get it to change back to white. I apologize if this is dumb, I'm not that good at this. Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Cheese</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Tegomin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src= "https://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
   
  
<style>
      ol {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      }

     li.bar {
     float: left;
     }

     .bar {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     }

     
     .bar:hover {
     background-color: black;
     }
     
    </style>

</head>

<body>
 <nav>
     <ol>
       <li class = "bar"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as1.html">H2</a></li>
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as2.html">H3</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="divs.html">H4</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as4.html">H5</a></li>  
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as5.html">H6</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="advcss.html">H7</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as7.html">H8</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as8.html">H9</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as9.html">H10</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as10.html">H11</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as11.html">H12</a></li> 
       <li class = "bar"><a href="as12.html">H13</a></li>
     </ol>
     </nav>
     
 <div class ="container">
 <h1>Look at all these cheese</h1>
    <div class= "slider">
        <img src="slide1.jpeg" width= "640" height = "426">
        <img src="slide2.jpeg" width= "640" height = "426">
        <img src="slide3.jpeg" width= "640" height = "426">
        <img src="slide4.jpeg" width= "640" height = "426">
        <img src="slide5.jpeg" width= "640" height = "426">
    </div>
 <ul id="paap">
      <li id="prev"><a href = "#">Previous</a></li>
      <li id="next"><a href = "#">Next</a></li>
 </ul>
 
 </div> 
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        pause: 1,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next'
    });
 });
 </script>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The list items `<li>` have been styled white, but they contain `a href's`, which you haven't styled at all, so they'll pickup the browser default style.

Add the following:

```
li.bar a {
  color: white;
}
```

That should style the text links white.

Answer (score 1):

by giving `color: white` inside class `.bar` will work on the text that is inside the element li with class `bar` .
Hence we have to target the anchor tag inside the li with class bar as follows:
`.bar > a{color: white;}`